# Why can't upload file pdf?

Tags: php, upload

this is html code:

```
  <form id="upload" action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <fieldset>
                <legend>html upload</legend>
                <input type="hidden" id="MAX_FILE_SIZE" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="300000" />
                <div>
                    <label for="fileselect">select file</label>
                    <input type="file" id="fileselect" name="fileselect[]" multiple="multiple" />
                    </div>
                <div >
                    <button type="submit">upload</button>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

code of upload.php:

```
 $myFile = $_FILES['fileselect'];
     $fileCount = count($myFile["name"]);
     for ($i = 0; $i < $fileCount; $i++) {


        $target_dir = "uploads/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename( $myFile["name"][$i]);


          //  echo  $myFile["tmp_name"][$i];
            if (move_uploaded_file( $myFile["tmp_name"][$i], $target_file)) {
                echo "The file ". basename(  $myFile["name"][$i]). " has been uploaded.";
            } else {
                echo "can not move";
            }

    }
```

If i upload file type is Image or MP4, they upload ok.

i try var_dump :
upload a image.

```
array(1) { ["fileselect"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "header.png" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "image/png" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpED23.tmp" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(32416) } } } The file header.png has been uploaded.
```

Upload a pdf:

```
array(1) { ["fileselect"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(15) "Untitled-12.pdf" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(2) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } } } can not move
```

But i can't upload file pdf.

Why can't upload file pdf?

Comment: What actually is the error message are you getting?

Comment: any errors? and does the pdf file is greater than `MAX_FILE_SIZE` value ?

Comment: error:  echo "khong the move";

Comment: size of file pdf only has 300kb

Comment: I suggest you ALWAYS check `$myFile["name"][$i]['error']` whenever you do an upload. It will normally show you what the problem is or at least lead you to the solution

Comment: i updated quesstion. error=0.

Comment: Has not tmp_name when upload a file pdf.

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is an issue, check the following line:

```
<input type="file" id="fileselect" name="fileselect" multiple="multiple" />
```

input file with multiple selection must have its name as an array so that it can hold multiple files name like:

```
<input type="file" id="fileselect" name="fileselect[]" multiple="multiple" />
```

Without this you cannot iterate over all the files.

Comment: thank,i miss when post question. but that is not my problem

Comment: Upload a pdf : array(1) { ["fileselect"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(15) "Untitled-12.pdf" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(2) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } } } can not move